# Search algorithm for excel document in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, ms-office

I'm writing a program to read an xslx file using Apache POI in java, and create a search algorithm to search for s string in the records. I've written the code to print all the records but I can't seem to find how to create the search algorithm. It's meant to show records with "zgheib" only. I would really appreciate a hand. This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Junaid\\Documents\\IntelliJ Projects\\ReadExcel_Bashar\\src\\assignment.xlsx"));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                switch (cell.getCellType())
                {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Instead of printing the cell values out, change that to test the value?

Comment: So it should check the values for both numeric and string types? Can you please write a code for me to see that

Comment: Numeric, String, Formula, Error - see http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents

Comment: I've already done that, what I need is the search algorithm. Please go through my code and question to clearly understand what I'm saying. Thank you

Comment: You have the string values of cells containing strings (`cell.getStringCellValue()`). What stops you checking whether this value equals your search string? Then, if it equals, do something with the `Row row` in this case. For example do collecting it in a `List<Row>`.

Comment: I'm kind of a beginner in Java, if you can post it as an answer with the appropriate codes, I'd appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the need is to get only rows where cell values contain a search string, then this can be achieved by traversing all rows and cells in the sheet and get the cell values. If the cell value contains the search string, then add the row to a list of rows `List<Row>`. Since all cell values must be converted to string as the search value is a string, [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) can be used. The `formatCellValue` methods of `DataFormatter` get all cell values as formatted strings. To support formula cells too, `DataFormatter` must be used together with [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html).

The following example provides a method

```
 List<Row> getRows(Sheet sheet, DataFormatter formatter, FormulaEvaluator evaluator, String searchValue) {
  List<Row> result = new ArrayList<Row>();
  String cellValue = "";
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    if (cellValue.contains(searchValue)) {
     result.add(row);
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  return result;
 }
```

This method traverses the given `sheet` and gets all cell values using `DataFormatter` and `FormulaEvaluator`. If found cell value contains the search value, the row is added to the list, else not. So the result is a `List<Row>` which only contains rows where cells contain the search string.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ReadExcelRows {

 //get only rows where cell values contain search string
 static List<Row> getRows(Sheet sheet, DataFormatter formatter, FormulaEvaluator evaluator, String searchValue) {
  List<Row> result = new ArrayList<Row>();
  String cellValue = "";
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    if (cellValue.contains(searchValue)) {
     result.add(row);
     break;
    }
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./inputFile.xlsx"));
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./inputFile.xls"));
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator =  workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  List<Row> filteredRows = getRows(sheet, formatter, evaluator, "zgheib");

  for (Row row : filteredRows) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    System.out.print(cell.getAddress()+ ":" + formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator));
    System.out.print(" ");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and the time you took to work this out. It worked perfectly. Thanks once again.